# Jquery: appending link in correct position

Tags: jquery, html

New to Jquery and after a long while trying to solve this, I thought best to just ask a question; so thanks in advance for any help.

At present the remove link is below each new "amount" row after the more button is triggered; however i want it to be to the side; in in the next row if you like.  I tried adding another hidden column and then appending the link to that row if you understand me but that just created more problems.  Is there a neat way of doing this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count


    // append for each div

$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $("#item").append('<div><input type="text" name="item" size="8"     </div>');
        $("#description").append('<div><input type="text" name="description" size="24" </div>'); 
        $("#qty").append('<div><input type="text" name="qty" size="4" id = \"a' + x + '\"></div>'); 
        $("#unit").append('<div><input type="text" name="unit" size="8" </div>');   
        $("#price").append('<div><input type="text" name="price" size="6" id = \"b' + x + '\"></div>'); 
        $("#discount").append('<div><input type="text" name="discount" size="4" id = \"c' + x + '\"></div>'); 
        $("#account").append('<div><input type="text" name="account" size="4" </div>'); 
        $("#taxrate").append('<div><input type="text" name="tax rate" size="16" </div>'); 
        $("#amount").append('<div><input type="text" name="amount" size="8" id = \"d' + x + '\"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');

    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;   
})
});
</script>

<style>
#container{
position:relative;
background-color: lightgrey;
height: 400px;
width: 1000px;
padding: 35px;
border: 25px solid navy;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 100px;
}

.indented {   
padding-left: 350pt;
}

input, label {
display:block;
}

#morebutton{
position: absolute;
top: 400px;
right: 0;
width: 1000px;
}

#remove{
float: left;
}



</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id = "container">


<div class ="input_fields_wrap">
<div id = "item" style="float:left;">
    <label for="name">Item</label>
    <input type="text" name="item" size="8">
</div>

<div id = "description" style="float:left;">
    <label for="name">Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="description" size="24">
</div>

<div id = "qty" style="float:left;">
    <label for="name">Qty</label>
    <input type="text" name="qty" size="4">
</div>

<div id = "unit" style="float:left;">
    <label for="name">Unit</label>
    <input type="text" name="unit" size="8">
</div>

<div id = "price" style="float:left;">
    <label for="name">Price</label>
    <input type="text" name="price" size="6">
</div>

<div id = "discount" style="float:left;">
    <label for="name">Discount</label>
    <input type="text" name="disc" size="4">
</div>

<div id = "account" style="float:left;">
    <label for="name">Account</label>
    <input type="text" name="account" size="4">
</div>

<div id = "taxrate" style="float:left;">
    <label for="name">Tax Rate</label>
    <input type="text" name="tax rate" size="16">   
</div>

<div id = "amount" style="float:left;">
    <label for="name">Amount</label>
    <input type="text" name="amount" size="8">
</div>

</div>

<div id = "morebutton">
<button class="add_field_button">Add More</button>
</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in jsfiddle?

Comment: I'll give it a go; never used it before though; I'm new to computer programming you see.

Comment: i tried to paste the code you wrote on a jsfiddle and this is what it comes out https://jsfiddle.net/dcbr6920/. Why don't you use a <table>? it looks more easy and logical as well as what you are printing out is actually a table

Comment: ah thanks; you did it before me; yours worked.

Comment: I intend for it to be a form; that's when i will be using php.  From what I've read, it seems tables and forms don't really go together, so i deliberately avoided tables.  Am i right in thinking this?

Answer (score 0):

I edited the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcbr6920/2/) to make it work with a table. I don't see which problems will you have in php using this structure. I'm pretty sure it will works fine with

```
<div id = "container">

<form>
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Item
      </td>
      <td>
        Description
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</form>

<div id = "morebutton">
<button class="add_field_button">Add More</button>
</div>

</div>
```

and your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count


    // append for each div

$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        var trClone = $('table tbody tr:first').clone();
        trClone.find('.remove_field').css('display', 'block');
        trClone.find('input').val('');
        $('table tbody').append(trClone);

    }
});

$('table').on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).parents('tr').remove(); 
    x--;   
})
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  About the form and tables thing, i may have got confused; i think it may be a problem only when you put form tags within tables; i just checked again.

Comment: i've been using <input>s inside tables in many projects and handling them in php with no problems

Comment: thanks for your help; i've updated - at least i hope - your jfiddle with my latest attempt which is working fine in jfiddle; however it's not working in xampp.  i assumed i had to put the css in an actual css document and link it in, as opposed to just putting it in the style section of html, however that doesn't seem to have made the difference.

Comment: although you're first jfiddle worked fine in my browser

Comment: it's a 3 instead of a 2 at the end of the url for jfiddle btw

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dcbr6920/3/    - works fine, thanks to your help; however i can't get it to work in my browser lol.

Answer (score 0):

With your provided html it's tough to do so. Here's my solution exact with your html. Here a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6w1uqjp/).

Just change your javascript to

```
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count

  var blankDiv = $('<div></div>');
  // append for each div
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      wrapper.find('div').each(function() {
        var $input = $(this).find('input').first().clone().val('');
        $input.addClass('after-' + x);
        blankDiv.html('').append($input);
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'amount') {
          blankDiv.append('<a href="" class="remove_field" data-remove="after-' + x + '" >Remove</a>');
        }
        $(this).append(blankDiv.html());
      })
    }
  });
  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    var remove = $(this).data('remove');
    $(this).remove();
    $('.' + remove).remove();
    x--;
  })
```

It will work in your case but still i suggest you to move to table like html.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count

  var blankDiv = $('<div></div>');
  // append for each div
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      wrapper.find('div').each(function() {
        var $input = $(this).find('input').first().clone().val('');
        $input.addClass('after-' + x);
        blankDiv.html('').append($input);
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'amount') {
          blankDiv.append('<a href="" class="remove_field" data-remove="after-' + x + '" >Remove</a>');
        }
        $(this).append(blankDiv.html());
      })
    }
  });
  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    var remove = $(this).data('remove');
    $(this).remove();
    $('.'+remove).remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 400px;
  width: 1000px;
  padding: 35px;
  border: 25px solid navy;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.indented {
  padding-left: 350pt;
}
input,
label {
  display: block;
}
#morebutton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  right: 0;
  width: 1000px;
}
#remove {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">


  <div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <div id="item" style="float:left;">
      <label for="name">Item</label>
      <input type="text" name="item" size="8">
    </div>

    <div id="description" style="float:left;">
      <label for="name">Description</label>
      <input type="text" name="description" size="24">
    </div>

    <div id="qty" style="float:left;">
      <label for="name">Qty</label>
      <input type="text" name="qty" size="4">
    </div>

    <div id="unit" style="float:left;">
      <label for="name">Unit</label>
      <input type="text" name="unit" size="8">
    </div>

    <div id="price" style="float:left;">
      <label for="name">Price</label>
      <input type="text" name="price" size="6">
    </div>

    <div id="discount" style="float:left;">
      <label for="name">Discount</label>
      <input type="text" name="disc" size="4">
    </div>

    <div id="account" style="float:left;">
      <label for="name">Account</label>
      <input type="text" name="account" size="4">
    </div>

    <div id="taxrate" style="float:left;">
      <label for="name">Tax Rate</label>
      <input type="text" name="tax rate" size="16">
    </div>

    <div id="amount" style="float:left;">
      <label for="name">Amount</label>
      <input type="text" name="amount" size="8">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="morebutton">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you.  Like i just replied to the guy below, I seem to be having a problem with the java in my browser.  I just swapped the java into my script and the button isn't doing anything now.  Is there something silly I'm forgetting to do?

Comment: @user1849962 which button you talking about?

Comment: the more button,  to add another row of fields.  I literally just swapped the java, that's all; and it's doing nothing; it was the same when i tried the other person's solution; everything works fine in jfiddle but not in the browser ... most strange.

Comment: Is it possible to get jfiddle to just produce a script combing all the three separate elements?  If so, I'll try that.

Comment: Java is working again.  But the code you suggested doesn't seem to work